# Filas com cheques e clientes

Tags: c

Quero criar uma queue ou pool.. de cheques.. como se fosse uma **Fila** de espera (FIFO) e tenho algumas dificuldades. Para já o código que tenho está me a dar alguns erros.

Estou a ter erros do genero:

```
Item.h:16:16: warning: struct has no members [-Wpedantic]
Item.c:22:8: error: ‘struct cheque’ has no member named ‘refc’
```

Código:

```
#ifndef _ITEM_
#define _ITEM_ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

   /* A chave pela qual se arruma os elementos e a refc*/
    #define key (a) (a != NULL ? a->refc : "")  

    #define less (a,b) (strcmp (a,b)<0)
    #define eq(a,b) (strcmp (a,b) == 0)
    #define NULLitem NULL

typedef long int* Key;                  /* Definir a chave, ponteiro */

typedef struct cheque {                 /* Nome da estrutura */
    int valor
    long int refe
    long int refb
    long int* refc
}*Item;     /* O Item vai ser um ponteiro para a estrutura */

Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int* refc);
void deleteItem (Item a);
void visitItem (Item a);

#endif
```

Comment: Miguel, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Da forma como está a sua pergunta fica a ideia de que quer que faça-mos para você o seu trabalho de casa. Para que o possamos ajudar deverá postar o que já tentou fazer e qual é a sua dúvida em concreto.

Comment: Já alterei para uma dúvida concreta. Sim preciso de ajuda no meu trabalho de casa porque não sei fazer a maior parte.. e por haver várias possibilidades de resposta nao sabia o que fazer. E sim tambem sou novo no stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Já descobri:

```
typedef struct cheque {                 /* Nome da estrutura */
    int valor;
    long int refe;
    long int refb;
    long int* refc;


}*Item;                         /* O Item vai ser um ponteiro para a estrutura */
```

Mas agora estou tendo outro tipo de erro:

> Item.c: In function ‘newItem’: Item.c:14:2: warning: implicit
>   declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>
> x->refc = strdup(refc);   ^ Item.c:14:10: warning: assignment makes
>   pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]   x->refc =
>   strdup(refc);
>
> Item.c: In function ‘visitItem’: Item.c:34:2: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *, but argument 2 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat=]   printf("refc: %p\n", a->refc);

---

```
    #ifndef _ITEM_
    #define _ITEM_ 

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define key (a) (a != NULL ? a->refc : "")      
    #define less (a,b) (strcmp (a,b)<0)
    #define eq(a,b) (strcmp (a,b) == 0)
    #define NULLitem NULL

    typedef long int* Key;                  

    typedef struct cheque {                 
        int valor
        long int refe
        long int refb
        long int* refc

    }*Item;                         

    Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int* refc);
    void deleteItem (Item a);
    void visitItem (Item a);

    #endif


----------
#include "Item.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int refc)
{

    Item x = (Item) malloc (sizeof(struct cheque));

    x->valor = valor;
    x->refe = refe;
    x->refb = refb;
    x->refc = strdup(refc);

    return x;
}


void deleteItem (Item a)
{
    free(a->refc);
    free(a);

}


void visitItem (Item a)
{

    printf("valor: %d\n", a->valor);
    printf("refe: %ld\n", a->refe);
    printf("refb: %ld\n", a->refb);
    printf("refc: %p\n", a->refc);

}
```